# What is the most intuitive and obvious copy link icon?

Tags: icon, interface-design

I'm building a blog interface and I need a button to represent my copy URL link action in my blog post pages. The button will be side by side with other social media share icons. I'm trying to decide between these 3 options. Which one is the most intuitive?

[image]

Comment: Is the URL itself displayed? In most cases where I've done something like this we show the URL that will be copied and have a "Copy" or "Copy URL" button next to it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/12KGU.png StackExchange does pretty much the same thing when you click "share" beneath a post.

Comment: That's a great solution, but in my case, the URL will not be displayed. It will be in the browser's address bar and the button is in the middle of the page. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Copy to clipboard` button is a relative new think compared to other internet and computer functionalities. So everyone is still "teaching" this process by including `Icon + Text`

## Options A & B

Options A & B will satisfy your needs **only if** they are accompanied by the link itself or a "**Copy Link**" text.

Examples:

### Google (mobile)

[image]

### Microsoft

[image]

### Apple (Instagram)

This proves it can be intuitive without any icon

[image]

---

## Option C

**Option C** should be used when you have two ways of copying to clipboard. For example: Copying content itself or content's URL as image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I think I'll use option A and put the text "copy link" next to the icon. Obrigada!

Comment: B does not lend itself intuitively as an icon to indicate `copy`, moreso just `url` - personally I would go with C + "copy link" text

Answer (score 2):

Your **option A** is a mere "Copy" button. It's like a `Ctrl + C` shortcut and it's not specifically related to links.

Your **option B** is a `hyperlink` button. Which is related to URL's for sure, but sometimes it's used in `Create hyperlinks` actions.

You should go with **Option C**, which combines the two actions. **Hyperlink AND Copy**.